# Search for a key,value in different lists which has different key orders

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tweepy

I am using tweepy to retrieve links in a json.I have extracted a list with dictionaries inside. Most of them are in the same pattern (same order for the keys and values) like below

```
[{'bitrate': 2176000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://A_LINK'},
{'bitrate': 632000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://B_LINK'}, 
{'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://C_LINK'}, 
{'bitrate': 832000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://D_LINK'}]
```

There are two characteristics of above pattern:

1.`{'bitrate': 2176000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://A_LINK'}` is at the FRONT of `{'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://C_LINK'}`

2.`{'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://C_LINK'}` is MISSING the key **Bitrate**

I want to find the url which has the bitrate of **2176000** (Which is **https://A_LINK** for the example),the below codes are **working** with above patterns which I can find **https://A_LINK**

```
link = next((item for item in x if item["bitrate"] == 2176000), None)

print(link["url"])
```

However, as  `{'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://C_LINK'}` is MISSING the key **Bitrate**

It will cause errors in the below patterns.

```
[{'bitrate': 632000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://A_LINK'},
{'bitrate': 832000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://B_LINK'}, 
{'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://C_LINK'}, 
{'bitrate': 2176000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://D_LINK'}]
```

For the above pattern,

`{'bitrate': 2176000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://D_LINK'}` is located  AFTER `'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL'`

Whenever I receive pattern like this, I receive error

`KeyError: 'bitrate'`

and I can't get the **https://D_LINK** AFTER `{'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://C_LINK'}`

Therefore I am asking, when I receive the 2nd list pattern,

is there a way to so-called "bypass"  `{'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://C_LINK'}`

so that I can get the **https://D_LINK** at last which has the bitrate **2176000**?

Thank you.

Comment: `dict.get(key_name)` would probably work for you. It returns `None` if the key is not present and doesn't raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: In your case, `link = next((item for item in x if item.get("bitrate") == 2176000), None)`

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
l = [
    {'bitrate': 632000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://A_LINK'},
    {'bitrate': 832000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://B_LINK'},
    {'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://C_LINK'},
    {'bitrate': 2176000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://D_LINK'},
]

''.join([d["url"] for d in l if "bitrate" in d.keys() and d['bitrate'] == 2176000])
```

Output:

```
'https://D_LINK'
```

Comment: Thanks, it is almost what I want. However the output in a list, Is there a way to output it as a string in you code?